# How can I get the ISRC and UPC code from an audio file with python mutagen

Tags: python, id3, mutagen, id3v2

I have a music file (bought on amazon). With this service https://www.get-metadata.com I figured out, that there is a upc and isrc code somehow in the file. The data is in this tag "Id3V2 Priv.www.amazon.com" and inside a xml.

My problem is, that i can't figure out, how to get this information with the python mutagen library. I could print out some xml data but I couldn't figure out how this is supposed to be done with mutagen.

Comment: Maybe you need to get the data with mutagen and then read it with an xml library.

Comment: I was thinking the same at first but than I saw this: https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html#id3v2-3-4-frames. It is in the documentation but i am having a hard time to understand how to use it.